# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. EF Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2, ef-core-2.2, ddd-repositories

i need some help with this problem, i using EF Core 2.2 and ASP.Net Core 2.2

i'm trying to delete some phones from my entity (User) but when execute dbcontext.SaveChanges() generate a exception: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

My UserService

```
User entity = _userRepository.GetById(model.Id);

var numbers = GetDeletePhoneNumbers(model, entity.UserPhones.ToList());

foreach (var number in numbers)
{                
   entity.RemoveUserPhones(_userPhoneRepository.GetByPhoneNumber(number));

   _userRepository.Modify(entity);
}
```

My method to get delete's Phones

```
 private List<string> GetDeletePhoneNumbers(UserModel model, List<UserPhone> userPhones)
 {
    return userPhones.Where(c => !model.Phones.Any(u => u.Number == c.Phone.Number)).Select(c => c.Phone.Number).ToList();
 }
```

And my RepositoryClass

```
protected override void InternalModify(TEntity entity)
{           
    this._dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Update(entity);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();           
}
```

my StackTrace of the Exception

> System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.ValueCollection.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()

ty for the help...

Comment: what does "RemoveUserPhones" do? Besides that - you save on each iteration? Why not save after the foreach?

Comment: hi, "RemoveUserPhone" only remove the phone from the list of the entity. 

i'm trying to save after foreach, but don't work 

public virtual void RemoveUserPhones(UserPhone userPhone)
        {
            if (_userPhones.Contains(userPhone))
            {
                _userPhones.Remove(userPhone);
            }
        }

Comment: try to place the save after the iteration - otherwise you'll work on a collection which is no longer the actual state of the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `foreach` loops assume an immutable collection to iterate over it. That is, the collection can't be modified while the loop is happening; in other words, the collection when the loop begins must remain the same throughout the loop's execution.

Therefore, modifying the state of the collection while the loop is happening causes an exception to be thrown. This has nothing to do with EF, it's a characteristic of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: yup, i think the problem is the foreach, but i tried another way, but the problem persist...

Comment: @jmoyau What do you mean when you say that *you tried another way*? Post more code.